# Does Adam West-era Batman ever mention his parents?

Tags: dc, batman, batman-1966

With the camp and saccharine kid-friendliness of 60's Batman, I'm legitimately curious if they even had the ability to mention that a character was murdered, even if it's off-screen and decades before the start of the show.

Comment: I didn't know "camp" = "kid-friendly". I thought "camp" = "gay-friendly".

Comment: @user14111 It doesn't mean either of those things. See this wikipedia article on camp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_(style)

Comment: @DCShannon "ostentatious, exaggerated, affected, theatrical; effeminate or homosexual; pertaining to, characteristic of, homosexuals." So I was all wet. Shoulda looked it up. Live and learn. Mea culpa.

Comment: In addition to the correct direct answer already offered, I would add that the premise of the question is incorrect: they have a character actually die during the second episode - Riddler's henchwoman is chased by Batman to his atomic reactor in the Batcave (I'm not making this up) and falls to her death.

Comment: I saw re-runs as a kid, but it's hard to imagen this  show was actually on the air. And just for people that havent seen it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpoxHvmWPfc

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Yes, in the very first episode

When approving some Wayne Foundation spending, Bruce remarks:

> **Bruce:** My resources are behind you... in full.
>
> **Harris:** You're a real champion, Mr. Wayne.
>
> **Female visitor:** Indeed you are.
>
> **Bruce:** Don't mention it, Mr. Harris. Perhaps if there had been anti-crime centers of the type you now propose when my parents were murdered by dastardly criminals...
>
> <sup>*Batman* Season 1 Episode 1: "Hi Diddle Riddle"</sup>

There's another mention later in the episode, when Bruce is contemplating having to give up his crime-fighting identity in the face of a wrongful arrest suit from the Riddler:

> **Alfred:** A million dollars...
>
> **Bruce:** It's not the money, Alfred, it's the idea of it: my identity revealed, my value as a secret crime-fighter ended, everything I've trained myself for since my parents were murdered, in the ash-can.
>
> <sup>*Batman* Season 1 Episode 1: "Hi Diddle Riddle"</sup>

Comment: Crap. Looks like I owe a guy a drink.

Comment: My parents weren't just murdered by mere *murderers*; they were murdered by *dastardly criminals*!

Comment: @KyleStrand as long as it wasnt Joe Chill